# Insert if not exist otherwise update on two tables in the same query

Tags: mysql

So I been reading that mysql does not support insert into multiply tables.
you need actually to do two or more INSERT INTO in the query. But my problem is update two tables but insert if one does not exist. is it possible to do in just one query ?

I have this.

```
UPDATE user, userdetails SET
userdetails.firstname   = ?,
user.username       = ?,
user.email              = ?,
userdetails.location    = ?
WHERE user.id               = ? 
AND userdetails.user_id     = ?

$values = array($firstname,$username,$email,$location,$_SESSION['id'],$_SESSION['id']);
```

But its not always something into the last row

```
 AND userdetails.user_id='{$_SESSION['id']}'
```

Ill been also read
`DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but that should not work since they are more than one table ?

I could easily create a query that insert user_id into userdetails.user_id by default when the user registered but it would be much nicer to have it the query.

Comment: If you can use placeholders, use it for **any** and **all** user data, including anything in `$_SESSION`. Why you're exposing yourself to a possible SQL injection bug is mystifying.

Comment: @tadman your right. updated that.

Comment: The operation you're after is a [MERGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) statement.  Unfortunately, AFAIK, it is not supported by MySQL.

Comment: For "insert if one does not exist" you can use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT` statement does not support adding records to multiple tables simultaneously. For that you want a simple transaction:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_a (...)
INSERT INTO table_b (...)
COMMIT
```

If there's an error when inserting into `table_a`, it is possible to rollback to the beginning of your transaction. This is the SQL standard way of doing things.

You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` to update records in place if they already exist, or the non-standard MySQL `REPLACE INTO` which will delete any conflicting records and replace them with your data.

Comment: Thank you! 
That its was I was looking for.
Will take a break and try it in an hour. thank you again